# Applying different rules when Hovering over an Active link

Tags: css

I'm currently working with a set of links that are getting their background images replaced when they are focused, hovered over, and non-focused; but right now I also need to fix it so that when you hover a focused link you'll get yet another result.  My searching hasn't found anything and my experiments with anything like:

```
a:focus:hover { background:url(image.url) no-repeat;}
```

have met with less than desired results.  Does anyone know of way to simply do what I'm trying for?

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work, but focus won't work in IE without a valid doctype, so I doubt :focus:hover will fare any better.

Comment: That's what I thought should work too, but so far hasn't work the way I thought it would. I was thinking there might be an alternate method.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found, that method does work; but only when you remember to include the class and sub-class names that you are applying to an item.

Comment: Ahh... yes... the devil is in the specificity.